# Who keeps track of the last read message offset of the consumer in Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In Apache Kafka, who keeps track of the last message read by the consumer? And also who keeps track of which consumer group ID reads from which partition? Is all this information is in the zookeeper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every consumer group maintains its offset per topic partition. Since `v0.9` the information of committed offsets for every consumer group is stored in this internal topic (prior to v0.9 this information was stored on Zookeeper). When the offset manager receives an `OffsetCommitRequest`, it appends the request to a special compacted Kafka topic named **`__consumer_offsets`**. Finally, the offset manager will send a successful offset commit response to the consumer, only when all the replicas of the offsets topic receive the offsets.

---

Regarding your question about *partition assignment*, Kafka uses [`partition.assignment.strategy`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#partition.assignment.strategy) to determine how partitions are assigned to consumers. This propertydefaults to [`RangeAssignor`](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/RangeAssignor.html):

> The range assignor works on a per-topic basis. For each topic, we lay
>   out the available partitions in numeric order and the consumers in
>   lexicographic order. We then divide the number of partitions by the
>   total number of consumers to determine the number of partitions to
>   assign to each consumer. If it does not evenly divide, then the first
>   few consumers will have one extra partition. For example, suppose
>   there are two consumers C0 and C1, two topics t0 and t1, and each
>   topic has 3 partitions, resulting in partitions t0p0, t0p1, t0p2,
>   t1p0, t1p1, and t1p2. The assignment will be: C0: [t0p0, t0p1, t1p0,
>   t1p1] C1: [t0p2, t1p2]

The other two options are [`RoundRobinAssignor`](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/RoundRobinAssignor.html) and [`StickyAssignor`](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/StickyAssignor.html)

Comment: sorry, I did not understand `internal topic` in `committed offsets for every consumer group is stored in this internal topic`. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Ash It depends on how your consumers commit their offsets. The default behaviour is `enable.auto.commit=True` which means that your consumers will automatically be committing their offsets every `auto.commit.interval.ms`. Alternatively, you can choose to commit the offsets manually so that you can have full control.

Comment: @Ash Firstly, when you're asking a question as a comment, don't delete it afterwards especially when somebody has replied. Secondly, can you be more specific about what you did not understand?

Comment: Just correct me if I am wrong, so there is an internal topic in Kafka for maintaining the consumer's last commit message offset.

Comment: @Ash Yes, that's correct. (It doesn't store _just_ the last committed offset though)

Comment: Understood that partitions are assigned to consumers based on strategy like round-robin. But where is this information stored after assigning the consumer to the partition?